# Morphia dot-notation query on @Reference field

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, morphia

I am querying my 'schede' collection, whose documents look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5499f0f74b9037f6efcb4e00"),
    "className" : "it.trew.omg.model.SchedaLavoro",
    "dataInserimento" : ISODate("2014-12-23T22:47:19.664Z"),
    "dataAggiornamento" : ISODate("2014-12-23T22:54:27.426Z"),
    "titolo" : "prima",
    "descrizione" : "my project",
    "dataInizio" : ISODate("2014-11-30T23:00:00Z"),
    "dataFine" : ISODate("2014-12-02T23:00:00Z"),
    "aperta" : true,
    "cliente" : DBRef("soggetti", ObjectId("5495d48c4b909c169ce5d33e"))
}
```

"cliente" references a document from the "soggetti" collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("549889a24b90f32e51dc2e0c"),
    "className" : "it.trew.omg.model.Soggetto",
    "dataInserimento" : ISODate("2014-12-22T21:14:10.850Z"),
    "dataAggiornamento" : ISODate("2014-12-22T21:14:10.850Z"),
    "ragioneSociale" : "Stefania"
}
```

In my entity code (SchedaLavoro corresponds to the 'schede' collection), it is: `@Reference Soggetto cliente;`

Now my search query is working like that:

```
public List<SchedaLavoro> findByQuery( String queryTerm ) {
        Query<SchedaLavoro> query = createQuery();
        if ( !queryTerm.isEmpty() ) {
            query.or(
                query.criteria("titolo").containsIgnoreCase(queryTerm),
                query.criteria("descrizione").containsIgnoreCase(queryTerm)
            );
        }
        query.order( "-aperta, -dataInserimento");
        return query.asList();
    }
```

I would like to add this to my "or" criteria list:

```
query.criteria("cliente.ragioneSociale").containsIgnoreCase(queryTerm)
```

but I get this error:

> Can not use dot-notation past 'cliente' could not be found in
>   'it.trew.omg.model.SchedaLavoro' while validating -
>   cliente.ragioneSociale

**How can I query on fields of a referenced sub-document?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Reference` documents are not subdocuments.  you can't query across them like that.  What you're trying to do is a join and mongodb doesn't support that.  you'll have to do two different queries.

Comment: So.. how would you adapt my code above? I suppose my second query should be on the 'clienti' collection, then I will filter my first query results list basing on the second query results, that's right?

Comment: Query once against the "soggetti" collection and get that ID value then query against the "schede" collection using that ID to filter.